# Python: test string for with non-adjacent repeated characters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to test a string against a pattern which contains non-adjacent repeated characters. For example, if pattern is `12xx5xxx3`, the following would pass:

```
120050003
121151113
```

And the following would fail:

```
120051113
120050004
```

I’ve written the following code which works, but there’s gotta be a more elegant way to do this. Perhaps list comprehension or regex. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def match_pattern(pattern, test):
    if len(pattern) != len(test):
        return False
    repeat = []
    for i in range(0,len(pattern)):
        if pattern[i] == 'x':
            repeat.append(i)
        else:
            if pattern[i] != test[i]:
                return False
    repeat = [test[x] for x in repeat]
    return len(set(repeat)) == 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your general pattern `12xx5xxx3` we can form the following regex pattern:

```regex
12(.){2}5\1{3}3
```

Here is a sample script which uses `re.search` to assert if an input match or not:

```py
inp = "121151113"
if re.search(r'^12(.){2}5\1{3}3$', inp):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! I tried Googling but couldn't figure it out: does the `\1` make a reference to the first `(.)` caught by this regex pattern? In order words, if I have two `(.)` and I want to refer to them later in the regex pattern, I can just do `\1` and `\2`? Thanks again!

Comment: @fuzzy_logic Everything you said in your comment above is correct `:-)`

Comment: Great thanks! Seems like it’s worth spending a bit of time to read up on regex...!

Comment: Yes...regex is a very useful tool for anyone doing technical work.